# .jar file doesn't open by double clicking, but works through cli

Tags: windows-10, java

`java -jar file.jar` works fine, but if I double click on it nothing happens.

I've tried everything I could find but nothing seems to fix this. I've checked regedit, file associations, uninstalled oracle java and tried open jdk, tried different version of java, etc. The problem remains.

Regedit has `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\jarfile\shell\open\command` correctly set. File associations on windows are also correctly set. When I double click on the jar file, java runs (a cmd window quickly appears and then disappears) but nothing happens.

```
> java --version
java 15.0.1 2020-10-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 15.0.1+9-18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 15.0.1+9-18, mixed mode, sharing)

> assoc .jar
.jar=jarfile

> ftype jarfile
jarfile="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1\bin\java.exe" -jar "%1" %*
```

How can I fix this so that I can open the file by double clicking on it?

Comment: "I've checked regedit, file associations" .. not enough information here.. checked WHAT?  .. I ask because your answer lies in the association of .jar files and nothing else.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Regedit has HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\jarfile\shell\open\command correctly set. File associations on windows are also correctly set. When I double click on the jar file, java runs (a cmd window quickly appears and then disappears) but nothing happens.

Comment: COOL!  Now we are cooking  but you need to put that in your question, not a comment (for later).. You are correct about where your base association go but Microsoft added another STUPID layer of associations under HKCU.  Lemme figure out where those are again..

Comment: I have your solution.  If it works, post it for yourself.. wait a couple of days and accept your own answer (you need the points and I am lazy).  You want to go to `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.jar` and look there. :)  I myself would delete this key.  That should force the associations back to the HKCR key you mention.. back it up if you want.. or you can figure out the new registry keys in the location I mention.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I deleted that key but it still doesn't work.

Comment: How are you supposed to interact with this JAR program? GUI? Interactive shell?

Comment: @gronostaj it's basically a key logger that just sits silently in the background. Only has a system tray icon. It worked fine before, so I know it's a problem with windows and not the app itself.

Comment: @gronostaj , what does how he is going to interact with a program have to do with windows explorer file associations?  I am not questioning you.. I am honestly curious how this matters?

Comment: Poke around `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileAssociation` and see if there is a clue there as to what is happening.  If that doesn't help, there is always the tried and true process monitor and snooping what keys the explorer is looking at.

Comment: OH!  And duhhhh (on my part).. `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\jarfile\shell\open\command` doesn't mean anything if `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.jar` isn't pointing to `jarfile`

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas thank you! `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.jar` was pointing to `.jar_auto_file`, which called java without the `-jar` argument. Making `.jar` point to `jarfile` fixed the problem! Feel free to post an answer and I'll gladly accept it!

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas My first thought was that the program is used by calling it with some arguments and then exits immediately.

Comment: No bro.  You take the points.  Write up what you did to solve it.. you might talk about the file associations and why the information you read online did not work for you. :)

Comment: @gronostaj .. TOUCHE' !! That is exactly what the problem was.. he just needed help figuring out what keys were pointing in the wrong direction. :)

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Well, not exactly. It was Java that was being called incorrectly, not the program itself. The theory I was trying to test was "the program works as intended, prints output and exits immediately; OP complains because the window doesn't stay on screen". The missing `-jar` was a more subtle issue :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @SeñorCMasMas for helping me solve the problem.

Editing `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.jar` to point to `jarfile` instead of `.jar_auto_file` fixed the problem.